# How to make TrackBar balance in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, trackbar

here is my new problem

I have set TrackBar1, Max to 200,Frequency to 10,Position = 100, 
what i want is something like this, it move from -100..0..100.

Also, how to make the slider move to each needle bar? Thank you..

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Trackbar1.Position);
  end;

end.
```

Comment: ...then set the `Min` to -100. Also, don't ask two different questions within one question.

Answer (score 1):

To move the thumb by the steps of the `Frequency` value set the `Frequency` property to 10 and `TickStyle` to `tsAuto` in your case. To setup the range to the negative values simply do that by setting the `Min` property value to -100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Min := -100;
  TrackBar1.Max := 100;
  TrackBar1.Frequency := 10;
  TrackBar1.TickStyle := tsAuto;
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
end;
```